bootJar task fails with Gradle 8.5 and Spring Boot 3.3.0, caused by Spring Boot Gradle plugin's usage of Apache commons compress library
I have the following setup:
Gradle: 8.5
Spring Boot 3.3.0
Kotlin: 1.9.23

Before I used Spring Boot 3.2.6, and after update to the latest version I encounter the following error when running bootJar task or any task depending on it:
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveOutputStream.putArchiveEntry(org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry)'
at org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.bundling.BootZipCopyAction$Processor.processDirectory(BootZipCopyAction.java:261)
at org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.bundling.BootZipCopyAction$Processor.process(BootZipCopyAction.java:241)


By checking the latest codebase of Spring Boot Gradle plugin, I was able to find the line mentioned in the stack trace. So the issue should be the wrong version of org.apache.commons.commons-compress library being used in the Spring Boot 3.3.0 Gradle plugin.
I see that I have different versions of org.apache.commons:commons-compress library present in the external dependencies of my project - 1.22, 1.24.0, and I believe one of those versions is used in Spring Boot plugin, where the aforementioned method is not available (I also use Testcontainers, so not sure which exact version corresponds to which dependency).
Unfortunately, I was unable to force the version 1.26.2 (latest at the moment) for the plugin, and I was also unable to find any similar question or issue raised regarding this.
I was hoping to find some answers to be able to upgrade to Spring Boot 3.3.0 successfully, and see if anyone else has encountered the issue and maybe has a workaround or even better a solution.

I had the same issue. In my case it was caused old version of commons-compress pulled as transitive dependency of testcontainers in buildSrc.
That dependency was totally invisible until I put a breakpoint in BootZipCopyAction class (line 261) and run the Gradle task in IntelliJ with Debug Gradle scripts mode. Then looking at ZipArchiveOutputStream classloader (out.getClass().classLoader) revealed that it used classloader from :buildSrc - ClassLoaderScopeIdentifier.Id{coreAndPlugins:settings[:]:buildSrc:}
In my case I fixed the issue by adding implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.26.2") to buildSrc/build.gradle.kts
Sad is that running of gradle buildEnv shows still incorrect version of the dependency (it displays version 1.25.0 although it now uses 1.26.2)

https://stackoverflow.com/users/17859414/martin-kvapil thanks a lot, this really solved the issue, I just added the implementation(...) with specific version to the buildSrc/build.gradle AND in another gradle module that I have in my multi-module project, and now the bootJar passes successfully! I can even see all other versions (1.22, 1.24, etc.) gone now that I manually added this.

I had the exact same problem. In my case, the buildtimetracker plugin was the problem.
Check your ./gradlew buildEnvironment and see if any version change of commons-compress lib like below
\--- net.rdrei.android.buildtimetracker:net.rdrei.android.buildtimetracker.gradle.plugin:0.11.0
 \--- gradle.plugin.net.rdrei.android.buildtimetracker:build-time-tracker-plugin:0.11.0
      +--- org.rauschig:jarchivelib:0.6.0
      |    \--- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.8 -> 1.25.0
      +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
      +--- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.3
      +--- org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:3.2.5.Final
      \--- joda-time:joda-time:2.4

after removing
    id("net.rdrei.android.buildtimetracker") version "0.11.0"

from plugins in root build.gradle.kts, bootJar tasks succeeded

Thanks for the suggestion. By running the task to all my modules, I was able to identify that an older version of the lib was being carried from com.github.davidmc24.gradle.plugin.avro:1.9.1 plugin that I use, but after removing it, still the same issue persists when running bootJar. And also I discovered that version 1.25.0 is used by Spring Boot 3.3.0 plugin, so if the method was not indeed removed from that version of lib - it should've worked fine.

@AdrianYepremyan Can you share the output of ./gradlew buildEnvironment? The method has not been removed, but its signature has been changed to a generic parameter. So, I presume older code can call a method with an outdated signature if there's a dependency version conflict, which may cause NoSuchMethodError.
You can find diff here: https://github.com/apache/commons-compress/compare/rel/commons-compress-1.24.0...rel/commons-compress-1.25.0

It was the com.jfrog.artifactory plugin in my case. Thanks for the hint.

For me the issue was resolved by adding the following BEFORE my plugins definitions in my (top-level) build.gradle
buildscript {
  configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force "org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.25.0"
    }
  }
}

This is because the issue was with the Spring Boot plugin dependencies not my application dependencies.

I had the same issue, in my case, it was because of the plugin
id "com.srcclr.gradle" version '3.1.12'


In our case it was avro-tools:1.11.3
upgrading to 1.12.0 fixed the problem

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.apache.avro:avro-tools:1.12.0'
    }
}

